# Linux: Make systemd kill a running Python script immediately?

Tags: python, linux, systemd, sigint

I am using `systemd` on Raspbian to run a Python script `script.py`. The `my.service` file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Python Script
Requires=other.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/home/script.py
ExecStop=/home/script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When the `Required=other.service` stops, I want `my.service` to stop immediately and also terminate Python process running `script.py`.

However, when trying this out by stopping `other.service` and then monitoring the state of `my.service` using `systemctl`, it seems like it takes good while for `my.service` to actually enter a '***failed***' state (stopped). It seems that calling `ExecStop` *to the script* is not enough to terminate `my.service` itself and the subsequent `script.py` in a minute manner.

Just to be extra clear: I want the script to terminate pretty *immediately* in a way that is analogous to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Basic Python clean-up is OK, but I don't want `systemd` to be waiting for a 'graceful' response time-out, or something like that.

Questions:

1. Is my interpretation of the delay correct, or is it just `systemctl` that is slow to update its status overview?
2. What is the recommendable way to stop the service and terminate the script. Should I include some sort of `SIGINT` catching in the Python script? If so, how? Or is there something that can be done in `my.service` to expedite the stopping of the service and killing of the script?

Comment: Have you tried using `BindsTo` instead of `Requires`?

Comment: @DougLuce That looks like a good suggestion in general. But I tried it now, and the state of in `systemctl` is still `my.service   loaded    deactivating    stop` for at least a minute before it becomes `loaded failed failed`

Comment: This is off topic here.

Comment: @black I don't think so, especially not if SIGINT capturing in Python is the required way to go.

Comment: What the question is mostly about is not that, that's why it's off-topic. Handling SIGINT would be, but it's secondary, apart from being almost surely already been discussed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should look into [`TimeoutStopSec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#TimeoutStopSec=) and it's default value param [`DefaultTimeoutStartSec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html#DefaultTimeoutStartSec=). On the priovided links, there are some more info about `WatchdogSec` and other options that you might find usefull. It looks like `DefaultTimeoutStartSec`'s default is 90 seconds, which might be the delay you are experiencing..?

Answer (score 1):

Under unit section options you should use `Requisite=other.service` This is similar to `Requires=` However, if the units listed here are not started already, they will not be started and the transaction will fail immediately.

For triggering script execution again under unit section you can use `OnFailure=` which is a space-separated list of one or more units that are activated when this unit enters the "failed" state.

Also using `BindsTo=` option configures requirement dependencies, very similar in style to `Requires=`, however in addition to this behavior, it also declares that this unit is stopped when any of the units listed suddenly disappears. Units can suddenly, unexpectedly disappear if a service terminates on its own choice, a device is unplugged or a mount point unmounted without involvement of systemd.

I think in your case `BindsTo=` is the option to use since it causes the current unit to stop when the associated unit terminates.

[From systemd.unit man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

Comment: added to my answer I thin you should use `BindsTo=` and that should be sufficient